# undefined method `before_pdf_post_process' for Image:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am using  mongodb with rails 4, I am beginner. I am getting "undefined method `before_pdf_post_process' for Image:Class", when I try to upload pdf/text_files/videos . I am using "mongoid-paperclip" for uploading.

How to include "processor code" in my code.

Please help me to sort this error at the earliest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to provide some code

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some minutes ago. The problem was the validations in the model. Add under your 
    `has_mongoid_attached_file :pdf`
the next validation line
    `validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]`

with the appropiate file extension. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I had forgot to add processor.rb file in initializer. After that it's working for me!!. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently the OP had a different issue, but this is the top hit on google, and I received the same error message.  For me, the solution was found here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1340

Per that issue-report:
"You need to put your validation code after the attachment declaration. These methods are somehow not accessible, until the 'has_attached_file' line."

I moved my validation line below the "has_attached_file" section in my model, and the error went away.